# Is this make error due to tab vs space issue or due to unsupported machine?

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, gnu

I am trying to run a simulation code on Ubuntu 16. **edit is 16 not 14**

When I run make all I receive the following error:

```
DIR bin exists
(cd src/gravity; make compile)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/athena4.2/src/gravity'
../../Makeoptions:99: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/athena4.2/src/gravity'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

So I have researched through many of the stack exchanges. What I have found is that typically this error is due to having some sort of issue between using tabs vs spaces.

Indeed when I look at the 99th line of Makeoptions I find spaces:

```
 ...
 41 #-------------------  compiler/library definitions  ----------------------------
 42 # select using MACHINE=<name> in command line.  For example
 43 #    ophir> make all MACHINE=ophir
 44 # New machines can be added to ifeq blocks below.
 45
 ...
 83 ifeq ($(MACHINE),zenith)
 84   CC  = mpicc
 85   LDR = mpicc
 86   OPT = -O3
 87   MPIINC = -I/opt/mpich2/intel/include
 88   MPILIB = -L/opt/mpich2/intel/lib -lmpich
 89   FFTWLIB = -L/usr/local/fftw3 -lfftw3
 90   FFTWINC = -I/usr/local/fftw3
 91 else
 92 ifeq ($(MACHINE),macosx)
 93   CC = gcc
 94   LDR = gcc
 95   OPT = -O3
 96   FFTWLIB = -L/opt/local/lib -lfftw3
 97   FFTWINC = -I/opt/local/include
 98 else
 99   abort Unsupported MACHINE=$(MACHINE)
100 endif
...
```

Now, I have tried using a tab instead and get a different error:

```
DIR bin exists
(cd src/gravity; make compile)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/athena4.2/src/gravity'
../../Makeoptions:99: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/athena4.2/src/gravity'
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

However,... I think that this may not be the ***REAL*** issue.

If you notice from the expert of the Makeoptions file, there are several machine options(only two that I showed). What I am wondering is, maybe my machine is not supported? since the Makeoptions lands on line 99 ?

Thus, maybe I should add an ifeq for my ubuntu machine?

I am able to run this on a mac.

Thanks for any help :)

****************************** Updated *******************************

Thanks to heynnema It seems fairly obvious that now I need to add a new machine to the ifeq block.

How do I determine the ??name?? I should use so that:

ifeq ($(MACHINE), ??name??)

returns true?

I have tried ??name?? = ubuntu

And this returns the same error what it gives me the unsupported machine.

*Meta question* Does this become a new question? *Meta question*

Comment: Review the various machine definitions, and see which one closely machines like a Debian/Ubuntu system, and then issue the `MAKE all MACHINE=xxx` command. Otherwise you'll have to guess at the various values in each ifeq block. You could also review the web site for specific installation instructions.

Comment: edits: "...closely matches machines..." and "replace the xxx with a supported machine name". Don't try and create your own ifeq block in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal:

```
grep -i 'ifeq ($(MACHINE)' Makeoptions
```

This will give you a list of supported machines. If you see your machine type in this list, then, in terminal:

```
make all MACHINE=the_name_of_a_supported_machine
```

If you don't find your machine type in the list, then you're on an unsupported machine.